# Add Minimum Order Charge to shopify cart based on cart totals

Tags: shopify

I need to add minimum order charges for customers when the cart total is less than 50. So  if user cart total is 35 then minimum order charges is 15.

Not the cart totals are

Sub total : $ 35.00

minimum order charges : $ 15.00

Cart total : $ 50.00

i have used bellow code to display minimum order charges on cart page

```
{% if cart.total_price < 5000 %}
    Minimum Order Charge :    {{ 5000 | minus: cart.total_price | money }}
  {% endif %}
```

but when i am going to checkout page the original totals are displaying. how can i get updated totals on checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just make up money in a cart. If the cart does not add up to 50.00 then the only way to make it add up to 50.00 is to add other products to the cart. If your product is worth 15.00 in this case, and the customer had 35.00 in there, you add the ID of the 15.00 product to the cart.

However that is a dumb pattern of use, since you cannot make up products worth $X easily. Your only action plan there is to make a one cent product. Then when you need 13.76 to make a 50.00 total, you would add a quantity of 1376 of the one cent product to the cart, to get your 50.00.

Another choice is to hide the checkout button till the cart adds up 50.00. Most customers will not figure out how to trick an order less than 50.00 into checkout... so that might work best for you here.

Comment: I don't want to add any other product tot cart. because if add a dummy product to makes cart total 50.00 in the checkout page user don't understand whats happened there

<pre><code>
X product               1X26.24      : 26.24
Dummy product    1376X0.1   : 13.76
<code></pre>
User didn;t understand what is "Dummy product". that's why i need to add remaining amount (13.76) as "minimum order charges "